# arm_navigation problem with sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

### I'm fairly new to ROS and especially the ROS packages for industrial robotics and automation applications. when I was creating a package,I have used the link "http://code.google.com/p/swri-ros-pkg/" to download "sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation".  For that I have created a package and relevant folders with files (folders like config, launch and src). Than I tried to build above mentioned package and I was known that have to implement arm_navigation stack for dependencies. After that, I tried to build necessary packages from arm_navigation stack. I have unsuccessful with ompl_ros_interface. It was given the following error message even through I have successfully build the ompl package.

mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package ompl_ros_interface
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
-- checking for module 'ompl'
--   package 'ompl' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
CMakeLists.txt:20 (pkg_check_modules)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ompl_ros_interface written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/sameera/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120525-015900/ompl_ros_interface/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ompl_ros_interface [FAIL] [ 1.74 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ompl_ros_interface.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 63 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/sameera/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120525-015900

---

I was just wondering if there's a proper method to overcome the above problem.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34795/arm_navigation-problem-with-sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation/) by [samee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2455/samee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't need to build arm_navigation from source - just apt-get install ros-fuerte-arm-navigation.  If you do want to build from source on fuerte you'll need to install the separate ompl deb using 'sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ompl'.  If you have other issues using ros-industrial code with fuerte

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0